# Search and replace string and ignore null byte character

Tags: c, string, replace

I'm working on a C program that uses NFQUEUE to filter traffic for another application. One of the things I need to do is replace a string contained within a packet, with another string.

The problem is, the packets seem to contain the null terminator byte randomly (in the middle of the string). This means that most solutions I see, using strstr(), don't work. I need to find something similar that doesn't stop upon reaching a null terminator byte, but rather allows for a length to be specified and uses that instead. (nfq_get_payload() returns a length.)

I've looked at replacing the null bytes with another byte before performing the replace, and then restoring the null bytes before the packet is sent off. The problem with that approach is there's a chance the packet could contain the character, so that wouldn't be the best approach. I suppose I could also find a random byte that is not contained within the packet, but I'd rather avoid doing all that.

edit: Both the original string and replacement string are the same length, which is 13 characters.

Comment: *the packets seem to contain the null terminator byte randomly* -- Get a protocol and traffic specification, so that you know exactly when and why these nuls are there. Modifying traffic of which you don't understand the format may break the application and gets you into a debugging hell, with all kinds of possible side effects, including the loss of user data.

Comment: It's a closed source application with no specifications available from the developer, so unfortunately that's not an option.

Comment: Aren't just just looking for a special bit-pattern instead of a string?

Answer (score 1):

You might be satisfied with [`memchr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7zdhf37%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) if finding one character can work for you. Otherwise, you would have to make a `memmem` implementation yourself or find one online.

Be aware that string-searching algorithms (because that's what `memmem` is) can have a wide range of performance characteristics, so you want to find one based on a performant algorithm (e.g. [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore%E2%80%93Horspool_algorithm) looks acceptable, but your mileage may vary).